# Manually load the driver

Tags: .net, ado.net, connection-string

How to load an ADO.NET driver *but* when a connection is needed I want to specify the connection string *manually* which means through my code and without having it in the config file ?

If there's no way to do this, what's the best approach to achieve this, knowing that I'm writing an app that manages different databases (so different DBMS) that are inputted by the user himself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find plenty of examples here:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Example (using http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgre-sql):

```
var connection = new PostgreSqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword");
connection.Open();
```

You can use db provider factory for interface based programming instead if driver specific.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(VS.80).aspx

To create a factory:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z.aspx

**Edit**

I think I understand what you are looking for. To load the actual driver **assembly** at runtime. You can do that using the `DbProviderFactory`. You don't need to add any driver specific references to your project when using it. However, the drivers must be installed on the computer =)

Comment: That wasn't quite the goal of my question, but I've just figured out that ADO.NET can do what I'm planning to, I didn't know it could load the correct driver according to the passed in connection string. Besides, thank you for your collaboration :)

Comment: Please elaborate what your looking for then.